# ngx-tinymce-editor has no exported member 'NgxTinymceModule'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am trying to implement **[ngx-tinymce-editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-tinymce-editor)** into my project, but there seems to be a roadblock here. Is this an error with the plugin itself, or am I missing something here.

```
ERROR in src/app/components/article/article-submit-form/article-submit-form.module.ts(4,10): error TS2305: Module '"*Project Path*/web/node_modules/ngx-tinymce-editor/ngx-tinymce-editor"' has no exported member 'NgxTinymceModule'
```

This is how my component that I am trying to include the tinymce editor in:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { ArticleSubmitFormComponent } from "./article-submit-form.component";
import { SharedModule } from "../../shared/shared.module";
import { NgxTinymceModule } from "ngx-tinymce-editor";

@NgModule({
    imports: [SharedModule, NgxTinymceModule.forRoot()],
    declarations: [ArticleSubmitFormComponent],
    exports: [ArticleSubmitFormComponent]
})
export class ArticleSubmitFormModule {}
```

I even tried including its module into `app.module.ts` but so far nothing happens the way it should.

I am using the default selector like so:

`<ngx-tinymce-editor [(content)]="content"></ngx-tinymce-editor>`

and I am getting the following errors:

`'ngx-tinymce-editor' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngx-tinymce-editor' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-tinymce-editor' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.`

and

`{
    "resource": "/d:/Projects/dev/SXNM-PROD/web/src/app/app.component.html",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#1",
    "code": "undefined",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Can't bind to 'content' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-tinymce-editor'.\n1. If 'ngx-tinymce-editor' is an Angular component and it has 'content' input, then verify that it is part of this module.\n2. If 'ngx-tinymce-editor' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.\n3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.",
    "source": "Angular",
    "startLineNumber": 54,
    "startColumn": 21,
    "endLineNumber": 54,
    "endColumn": 42
}`

but I have the ``` content = ``; ``` property added inside my component that needs tinymce.

Comment: Did you run `npm i tinymce` too ?

Comment: Yes. With the optional --save option

Comment: (save is automatically added in newer versions of npm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module is called "NgxTinymceEditorModule". Try importing that, the docs seem to show the wrong name.

```
import { NgxTinymceEditorModule } from "ngx-tinymce-editor";
```

and

```
imports: [SharedModule, NgxTinymceEditorModule.forRoot()],
```

Comment: Now I am getting the following error: `ERROR ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined
    at NgxTinymceComponent.push../node_modules/ngx-tinymce-editor/fesm5/ngx-tinymce-editor.js.NgxTinymceComponent.ngAfterViewInit (ngx-tinymce-editor.js:52)`

Comment: As far as I can see the component does not import tinymce by itself. YOu probably have to import it yourself.

Comment: I did, as you suggested in your answer.

Comment: My answer only shows the import of the component. The component also needs the tinymce library to function. Have a look at this https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/usage-with-module-loaders/ to import tinymce itself